# Derive Clone for array of something that is Clone?

Tags: rust, deriving

This code ([also on play](http://is.gd/C5YLyR))

```
use std::sync::Arc;

struct Foo {
    x: isize, // Something complex in actual code, implements Drop
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Good {
    a: Option<Arc<Foo>>,
    b: Option<Arc<Foo>>,
    c: Option<Arc<Foo>>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Bad {
    x: [Option<Arc<Foo>>; 3],
}

fn main() {
    println!("See?");
}
```

fails for `Bad` with

```
<anon>:16:5: 16:29 error: the trait `core::marker::Copy` is not implemented for the type `alloc::arc::Arc<Foo>` [E0277]
<anon>:16     x: [Option<Arc<Foo>>; 3],
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:14:10: 14:15 note: in expansion of #[derive_Clone]
```

but it has no problem with `Good`.

- Why is this and,
- is there any workaround? I am not exactly keen on handling 12 independent fields.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is in the [implementation of the `Clone` trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html):

```
impl<T> Clone for [T; 4] where T: Copy
```

That makes the *real* question: why do we require `Copy` to clone an array? [That implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/bfac337daab9b86971bcb3db61382ac44f94621c/src/libcore/array.rs#L31-L35) says:

```
fn clone(&self) -> [T; $N] {
    *self
}
```

So currently, a clone of an array is simply a bit-for-bit copy of the source array. A deeper *why* may be forthcoming from someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: More important question, should it be considered a bug (incomplete feature)?

Comment: Off-hand I wouldn't know how to automate the implementation . The code would have to be `[self[0].clone(), self[1].clone(), ..., self[N-1].clone()]` which is kind of hard to generate with macros.

Comment: @delnan : I think it's possible to do something out of this : http://is.gd/CQAIDd

Comment: @Levans Clever! I never thought it impossible, but I'm pleasantly surprised that it's so simple. Well, for certain values of "simple". Of course, that's completely unsafe for `A` that aren't fixed-size arrays, but it would be private anyway.

Comment: @JanHudec: The implementations of traits for arrays and tuples are quite limited today due to the lack of support for *value generic parameters* and *variadic generics* respectively. As a result there are "hacks" (generally macro abuses) to implement the traits for a small number of arities... so I would not be surprised if the implementation as it is was simply a quick attempt at moving on and not a fully thought out solution. So... a WIP. I would encourage you to raise a bug, and even better provide a patch; it could be a nice to have for 1.0!